# Map left mouse button in Karabiner Elements

Tags: keyboard, mouse, macos, keybindings

I want to map CapsLock to Left Mouse Button using Karabiner Elements in macOS Sierra.

I used to have such mapping in previous OS X versions using Seil and Karabiner but those no longer work in Sierra.

I tried to guess what should I put in the configuration JSON but failed.

```
"simple_modifications" : {
    "caps_lock" : WHAT_SHOULD_I_PUT_HERE?
},
```

Is it even possible to map Caps Lock to Left Mouse button in Karabiner Elements?

Comment: From looking at the examples, it doesn’t appear to be possible yet. If it does I think it might be a Complex Modification.

Answer (score 3):

BUT: it's actually quite simple (if I didn't mis-interpret your question):

Just select [Add item] in K.-Element's "Simple Modifications" tab, choose "caps_lock" (left) and "button1" (right) – and you're DONE!

… no need for "Complex Modifications", btw.